# How do I configure a Bluetile session in GDM?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, gdm

As you Ubuntu folks know, Canonical has switched away from the gnome desktop in favor of Unity for Natty. However, you can still access Gnome through a "classic" option in the login screen. Since I can't live without bluetile (a tiling window manager) I've been sticking with the "classic" option but then launching bluetile every time I turn on my PC. (Before Natty, there was a "gnome + bluetile" option available on login that made this unnecessary.)

My question is, what's the Right Way to configure my box to once again have a working "gnome + bluetile" option available on login? There is no documentation for this and it involves some pretty arcane linux/xwindows stuff I don't fully understand.

Is the correct answer to create a new file with the name
 `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/bluetile.session`? This is the best I've been able to guess. How do I found out the correct info for this file? Is there an example of this anywhere on the interwebs? I can't find any.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into the documentation under http://www.bluetile.org:

> One way to set up Bluetile as your default window manager under GNOME
>   is to make sure that the environment variable WINDOW_MANAGER contains
>   the path to the Bluetile binary before GNOME starts. This can be
>   achieved by putting something like the following line into ~/.gnomerc:
>
> export WINDOW_MANAGER=/home/user/.cabal/bin/bluetile

So, basically change metacity with bluetile and you're done.